# Python3 socket doesn't work - graphite

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, graphite

I created a function to send data to a graphite server. It sends the metricname, value and the timestamp to the graphite server at execution:

```
def collect_metric(metricname, value, timestamp):
   sock = socket.socket()
   sock.connect( ("localhost", 2003) )
   sock.send("%s %s %s\n" % (metricname, value, timestamp))
   sock.close()
```

This function above worked fine in Python2. I had to rewrite this function for Python3. Now no data will be send to graphite. No log entries in the graphite/carbon logs or something else ...:

```
def collect_metric(metricname, value, timestamp):
   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   sock.connect( ("localhost", 2003) )
   metricname = metricname.encode()
   if type(value) == "str":
      value = value.encode()
   timestamp = timestamp.encode()
   message = bytearray()
   message = bytes(metricname+b" "+value+b" "+timestamp)
   sock.sendall(message)
   print(message.decode())
   sock.close()
```

I receive no errors. Also on terminal I get the right format/output (see "print(message.decode())")

Has anybody some ideas why it doesn't work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The bytearray is without any encoding. Try this:
`message = (metricname+" "+value+" "+timestamp).encode("UTF-8")`

`sock.send(messages)`

Comment: That worked for me, but can I save this change an declare the bytearray with the encoding?

Comment: Sure. `bytearray(b"", "utf-8")`

Comment: Sorry but I have to correct my answer: unfortunately it still doesnt work. (I ran the old script too at testing). So I edited like above but it didn't help. Do you think this is an encoding problem?

Comment: I got always an error while trying to send a bytearray without encoding to server.

Comment: Have you deleted the `value = value.encode()` + metricname and timestamp?

Comment: The method socket.send() needs a bytearray. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send It is strange that I don't receive any error. Either at python or at graphite site.

Comment: Nevermind. I didn't convert the string into bytes, before using it in bytearray().

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're missing '\n' at the end of the message you're sending

```py
message = bytes(metricname+b" "+value+b" "+timestamp)
```

should be:

```py
message = bytes(metricname+b" "+value+b" "+timestamp + '\n')
```